# Multiple Spans In One Row with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, less, twitter-bootstrap

Using Twitter's Bootstrap's standard 940px fluid grid responsive grid I'm trying to get multiple `.span` div's in *one* `.row`.

I want to show a max of 3 `.span`'s on each internal line that grows with the page. So as more .span's are added they just get added to the `.row`.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="span4">1</span>
      <div class="span4">2</span>
      <div class="span4">3</span> 
      <div class="span4">4</span>  <!-- wrap to a new line-->                
      <div class="span4">5</span>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem I'm facing is that the span4 which wraps to a new line has the inherited left margin.  While I can fix this with nth-child() in modern browsers, it obviously still affects IE.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: what are you trying to do? why don't you just put them in two separate `.row`s? you can only fit 3 `.span4`s per row, and you don't even have any `div.row`s in your code.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I also want the rows to snap to two span's per line at a certain page width.  The problem I see is that if there are 5 span4's on two rows - how would I get the first span4 of the second row to appear next to the last span4 of the first row?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I decided to use the nth-child selector to remove the margin on certain .span's. So my final solution looked likes this:

One column of spans for 320px to 979px

Two columns of spans for 980px to 1409px

Three columns of spans for 1409px and up

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width:979px) { 
    /* one column */
    .row-fluid .span4 {width:100%}
    .row-fluid .span4 {margin-left:0;}  
}

@media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width:1409px) { 
    /* two columns, remove margin off every third span */
    .row-fluid .span4 {width:48.717948718%;}
    .row-fluid .span4:nth-child(2n+3) {margin-left:0;}
}

@media (min-width: 1410px) { 
    /* three columns, .span4's natural width. remove margin off every 4th span */
    .main .span4:nth-child(3n+4) {margin-left:0;}
}
```

For IE7 and 8 I set the width of each span to be 48.717948718% (so two per row) in the css - specifically targeting these versions by using html5 bolierplate .oldie html class. I then used Modernizr and a custom test for nthchild found at https://gist.github.com/1333330 and removed the margin for each even span, if the browser does not support the nth-child selector.

```
if (!Modernizr.nthchildn) {  
  $('.span4:even').addClass('margless');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your question specifies that you want columns to automatically wrap to the next line, but in Bootstrap's grid system `.span`s are specifically engineered to work within a `.row`, that's the grid. You're not using any `.row`s at all in your code. So my suggestion, if you stay true to the grid, is to have your code look something like this:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">1</div>
        <div class="span4">2</div>
        <div class="span4">3</div> 
        <div class="span4">4</div>  <!-- wrap to a new line-->                
        <div class="span4">5</div>  
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a jsfiddle that shows the OP's example and another for clarity. http://jsfiddle.net/qJ55V/5/

You have to use `.row` (not `.row-fluid`) in order to get the inherited styles applied to each column (span). Yes, it's extra markup, but not using `.row` will unfortunately cause your columns to jumble up.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but I just define a new css class in my custom stylesheet such as:

```
.margless{
    margin:0 !important;
}
```

Then I apply it to any element that I don't want to have margins.  I ran into the same thing using bootstrap and couldn't find an alternative solution.